# Program that allows keyboard shortcut for changing monitor brightness?

Tags: windows, display, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard

I have pangobright and Desktop lighter that allow me to control the monitor brightness (of my external monitor not just my laptop screen) by clicking on some things/sliding a bar

**I'm looking for a program that will let me use keyboard shortcuts to increase/decrease the external monitor brightness. See below for why fn keys will not work**  - Ideally, then I could put the keyboard shortcuts then on my red dragon gaming mouse which has 12 programmable side buttons

Why I want to constantly change brightness: When I'm using DarkReader extension on chrome, some pages will be very dark and I'll want the monitor brighter. Then I will go to a webpage with lots of bright pictures and then I'll want the monitor darker. If there were keyboard shortcuts, I could do this very rapidly

Brightness change is not on the F1 F2 keys of my USB keyboard. Nor would it matter I think given that I'm using a laptop attached to a monitor and it is the monitor I'm thinking about.

Unrelated to the post: I'm using a windows 8.1 laptop and a monitor that is sadly in korean and I can't interact with it directly using its own buttons since I don't know korean. This was my mistake buying a korean monitor

Comment: http://superuser.com/a/786076/387576